# How to Load IFrame after PageLoad

Tags: iframe, page-lifecycle

I have one page .aspx, and in page , I have put an iframe on header page.

Is it possible that `iframe` loads after page load finishes?

Comment: hi. thanks Aamir, i used E not good :D

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the src of the iframe empty then use Javascript to change the src when the document loads.

```
<body onload="function_to_change_iframe_src()">
    <iframe src=""></iframe>
</body>
```